# Animating updateview

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that represents asking a question such as do you prefer option A or option B (each button being an image). Then when the user chooses one of them, I change the question to do you prefer option C or option D? Now the view remains the same but the image and associated information can change. Therefore my question is this:

Just before asking the question I do:

```
[self updateView];
```

I was was wondering if this could be animated by flipping the screen for example.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens inside updateView? Based on your answer, I could suggest the use of UIView animations with blocks.

Comment: Inside updateView, I do:
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed"ImageforOptionC"] forstate:UIControlStateNormal];

I do the same for rightButton too.

I do a bunch of other things too but this is the part that I'd like to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in an animation:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{

    [self updateView];

}];
```

Other transitions you could use are:

- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`
- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown`
- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp`
- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom`
- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft`
- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight`
- `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop`